# Where to download SQL Server Report Designer for Visual Studio.NET 2008 for SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've already downloaded `Report Builder 2.0` to design report for `SSRS 2008`. Is there also a stand alone `Report Designer` for `SSRS 2008`? Or is it only available through installation of `SQL Server 2008`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you would have to install sql server 2008